# What is the effective tagging environment in case of an imported type?

Tags: asn.1

As an example let's assume the following setup:

A module definition A that has a tagging environment of explicit tags defines a type foo. And Module B with implicit tagging environment imports foo and assigns it to bar.

When reading a stream using module B it is not clear to me which tagging environment is effective. Does Module B define the tagging environment (implicit) of bar (being imported foo) or is the tagging environment of the module where it was declared (foo in Module A therefor explicit) effective?

I hope I explained the issue good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an import is not a textual thing like #include in C.  It simply makes types in other modules accessible without qualifying them using their module name.

X.680 13.1 Note 4 speaks specifically to your question:

> The value of "TagDefault" for the module definition affects only those
>   types defined explicitly in the module. It does not affect the
>   interpretation of imported types.

Note, however, that if in module B (where foo was imported), you write:

> Bar ::= [APPLICATION 5] Foo

This would be equivalent to:

> Bar ::= [APPLICATION 5] IMPLICIT Foo

because in module B, where the TaggedType is being defined, the tagging environment is implicit.

What the note means is that, if in Module A, you had:

> Foo ::= SEQUENCE { x [0] INTEGER }

then the tag on x is an EXPLICIT tag because the tagging environment in module A was explicit and that Foo will always be treated this way, even when being imported into module B with its implicit tagging environment.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a clear and precise answer to my question. You must have a really deep understanding of these things. That I find admiring and spooky at the same time :) It is so hard to have questions answered when it comes to ASN.1 related things.